# Как подключить разные классы?

Tags: php, классы

Привет, народ.

У меня такой вопрос возник.

Например, я написал 10 разных классов. Как их все подключить?

Например, мне нужнен 1 класс в файле index и функция из класса 7, в которой используется функция из класса 3.

Я знаю, что есть class, ClassName, extends, OtherClassName.
Классы я только начал изучать и пока новенький.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую изучить [namespace](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.php) и [autoload](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php). И подобных вопросов больше не будет)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше уже что-то из библиотеки SPL.

[`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Comment: lol. пол, когда красите, начинаете от дверей?

Comment: @VasyOk реквестирую развернутое обоснование

Comment: @Etki, если вы пройдете по ссылке "autoload", как начинающий сможете познакомится с разными механизмами автоматической загрузки классов, в том чисте и spl_autoloader_register. Это как по книге изучать с начало, а не с середины. Достаточно?

Comment: @VasyOk та я переходил по странице, на которую вы дали ссылку, там как раз и рекомендуют использование SPL. 

И еще использование `namespace` не всегда уместно.

Comment: ок. Я исходил из последнего предложения автора поста.